# Composing iOS Views

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I've created a view with a logout button and I'm trying to make that a subview of another view. The logout button view has a xib and a controller associated with the xib.

How do I make it so that this view/controller is a part of my other view?

The way I've done this before is by having a view that draws itself programmatically, drawing that view in the interface builder as part of another view and changing the class for that view. As I want that view to respond to methods, I made it have a protocol and then made the controller it was a subview of implement that.

Is that the only way to do it? Or is there a way such that I have an independent controller for my logout view that I can just 'drop in' into other views, because the drawback of the other method is that every view that wants to use this subview has to implement the protocol, even if that method is going to be the same in every view.

Answer (score 0):

Create a superclass to abstract the logout behavior.  Then, each UIViewController that supports the logout should subclass that superclass.  In the superclass, provide the method for logout.

This approach will enable you to either simply hook up UIControls in Interface Builder to the common IBAction in the superclass, or alternatively, even add specific customization in the subclass before invoking the superclass method.

Here's one possible example:

LogoutViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LogoutViewController : UIViewController
-(void)performLogout;
@end
```

LogoutViewController.m

```
#import "LogoutViewController.h"

@interface LogoutViewController ()

@end

@implementation LogoutViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)performLogout
{
    //do logout code
}

- (IBAction)logout:(id)sender
{
    [self performLogout];
}

@end
```

SomeOtherViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "LogoutViewController.h"

@interface SomeOtherViewController : LogoutViewController

@end
```

SomeOtherViewController.m

```
#import "SomeOtherViewController.h"

@implementation SomeOtherViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (IBAction)mySpecificLogoutButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    self.title = @"Good bye";
    // do other code specific to logging out from this UIVC
    [super performLogout];
}

@end
```

Comment: why do all those UIViewControllers have to be aware of this logout behaviour? Isn't there some way for me to have a view with a logout button and have a controller handle everything there, and simply make that a part of a view? That seems to be way more object oriented

Comment: I disagree that that approach is more object oriented.  In my proposed solution, each UIViewController that supports logout is defined as such via the superclass.  That being said, if you really want to take your approach, investigate the UIViewController containment API.  I do not think that is appropriate for this use case, as your logout button is likely to control the full UIView on the screen, not just a small part of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSNotificationCenter` for this. So you can post the notification on logout button action. You can check the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Hope this helps.